# Is the [career-development] tag a honeypot?

Tags: discussion, tags, migration

Essentially every post in [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development) is migrated or closed. Is this the purpose of the tag, to make these offtopic questions easy to find and then move? If so, are there other "honeypot" tags, or should there be? If not, should the tag instead trigger a message saying to ask this question elsewhere?

Comment: Funny :D / BTW this one made exception : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877314/book-recommendation-advice-for-a-future-cto

Comment: Shhhhhhhhhhhhh!

Comment: The tag dates from before the opening of Programmers. It's hard to think of a "career development" that *isn't* better there than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Damn, was going to ask this same question, but this original came up in the duplicate search. It's hard to find good questions to ask on meta!

Comment: There is now a site specifically for career development questions:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49221/career-development?referrer=vM2JF8RshPsqFxFwY0KYOQ2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nature of the [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development) tag is such that any question posted under it has a high likelihood of belonging on the [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site instead of StackOverflow.

However, be careful posting Career Development questions on Programmers.  They are [very specific](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) about the questions that are considered on-topic there.

Specifically:

> **Can I ask career advice questions?**
>
> Yes, within reason. Most career advice questions are specific to the poster's situation and run the risk of being closed. Try to generalize your situation into a good subjective question.
>
> Please be aware that we will not delete your career advice question after you receive answers if you change your mind about having asked it. Think carefully before you post a question full of personal or otherwise sensitive information. If you don't want something to be publicly revealed, consider not posting it on StackExchange.

and:

> **Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:**
>
> - What language should I learn next? (Unless you have a specific requirement and don't know which language meets that requirement.)
> - What salary/wage should I ask for/expect? (Too localized to your place and time)
> - Please critique my resumé. (Unless you have a specific question about a software development part of your resumé. Questions about resumé formatting and style are always off-topic.)

Comment: For those of you too lazy to click on our FAQ I've edited the relevant sections into Robert's answer.

Comment: @ChrisF - Thanks .. my mouse is just too heavy to move sometimes.

Answer (score 9):

[This is my new favorite thing](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/resume-feedback/1616#1616). Let me share it with you!

[image: question applies to all programmers]

A picture is worth a thousand words, eh?

Comment: A helpfull diagram for the FAQ to have, however it's also very obvious, especially as few questions posted apply to all programmers. Think carefully before using this graphic, particually "How would I feel about somone else if I had a question I obviously think is on topic because I posted it and they reply with this.".

Comment: @alan I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: You have 188k rep. I doubt it's the case. Not being rude is not that difficult, most manege it all the time.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the [career-development] tag a honeypot?

[Clearly yes.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcareer-development%5D%20closed:0)

In other news, looks like we are going to have to deal with 900 flags or so over the weekend.