# Could a few 'legacy' tags be switched to moderator-only to prevent future 'not-constructive' questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, moderator-tags

*Note:* I've asked a [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102303), but @Cody was right: I chose horrible examples and focused on the wrong things.  So:

**Question:** Certain tags on Stack Overflow remain as a by-product of allowing legacy questions life without flags.  Could these tags be changed to moderator-only (I realize the concept doesn't exist on SO yet) to prevent future not-constructive questions?

I've included *only two tags*.  **Please feel free to edit / change / alter / destroy this list**:

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) -- 514 questions with 16 asked this month
- [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development) -- 1252 questions with 25 asked this month

As to [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development) Cody noted: "a lot of questions that have been 'grandfathered-in' meaning that the tag can't be completely burninated, but also where it's very unlikely that new questions with that tag will be on topic"