# Can we have an option to import tag wikis from another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

If a tag has the same meaning on Programmers as it does on another Stack Exchage site, would it not be useful to be able to import the tag wiki or (less attractive) share the wiki with the other sites?

Perhaps the wiki body could be shared, and the tag line would need to be unique per-site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think too often, the tags on different sites have different semantic meanings.  So I wouldn't advocate one common repository of tags (for example).

However, if you like the tag wiki from Programmers, then just opt to edit it, copy the entries and paste them to the site of your choosing.

Comment: I did this. It seemed like a bad idea (copy-paste) when I did it. That is why I asked.

Comment: I've done it quite regularly when proposing synonyms where one tag has a nice wiki and the other is blank.  No worries!

Comment: Indeed the tags often have different meanings on different sites; something [you've learned the hard way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102303/could-certain-tags-on-stack-overflow-be-locked) :-p