# Blacklist career-development

Tags: discussion, tags

Not only blacklist, but perhaps put up a message 'if you thought this tag was appropriate, your question is almost certainly off-topic'?

In any case, I burned up a stack of close votes starting the cleanup process, but I'm no Hercules and the stable is Augean. Could I get some help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the \[career-development\] tag a honeypot?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92112/is-the-career-development-tag-a-honeypot)

Comment: Very clever, not-Hercules.

Comment: There is now a site specifically for career development questions.  Questions with the 'career development' tag can be migrated there:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49221/career-development?referrer=vM2JF8RshPsqFxFwY0KYOQ2

Answer (score 5):

From our [experience on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/offering-solutions-to-the-career-and-jobs-tags), tags with questions in them do not get blacklisted. Editing the tag wiki to say "do not use this tag" is also not a very reliable deterrent.

Orchestrating a mass clean-up of the questions in the [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development) tag is something we could do as a first step: vote to close and/or delete questions as appropriate. Some *might* be worth migrating to Programmers, but it'd have to be judged carefully and on a case-by-case basis.

It's pretty clear that these questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow now en masse, so it should be fairly easy to close and remove (where needed) these questions in preparation for removing the tag itself.

Comment: "Some might be worth migrating to Programmers" Oh, please don't...

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox There might be some good questions in there. Granted, the odds are low, but it could happen. :)

Comment: It's the en masse effect I'm more afraid of: a big number of high voted questions with good answers (one hopes) appearing on Programmers in short succession. That might create the perception amongst newer users that career development is a popular topic, and not one that should be avoided unless you have an absolutely excellent question. Something like: "I read ten questions about career development this month on Programmers, the crowd there can really help me with my (too localized / off topic / otherwise crappy) question."

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox Trust me, I'm aware of the problem it might create. I don't think we're necessarily in danger of en masse migrations any more than we are normally. (Plus we can always delete the migrated questions and/or reverse poor migrations.)

Comment: Yes we can. When (if) a clean up starts, you could also do a post on Meta P.SE, maybe some of us will join in and help avoid crappy migrations...

Answer (score -4):

If you're going to special-case a tag, why not offer to move the already-entered content to the programmers.se "Ask a Question" form?

If we have a good idea where such questions are on-topic, we should at a minimum point users there, instead of dismissing them with "it's off-topic".  After all, that's why questions get migrated instead of simply closed.

But if we can save the user the effort of re-entering their question on the other site, why not?

Comment: See Anna's answer... "Some *might* be worth migrating to Programmers, but it'd have to be judged carefully and on a case-by-case basis.". Automatically sending them to programmers would imply asking is fine there, which it most often won't be.

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm: I thought that was in reference to existing questions, not new ones.

Comment: Programmers.SE is not a catch-all for these kinds of questions.  Few of them are actually on-topic there.

Comment: @BenVoigt At a cursory glance at the existing career development questions, most of them would not make good Programmers questions (or good questions, period).

Comment: @BenVoigt P.SE career development questions: [119 closed](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcareer-development%5D+closed%3A1) / [152 open](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcareer-development%5D+closed%3A0). 43.91% closed, not counting deleted questions. Pointing users towards P.SE would obviously not be a good idea.