# Burninate: career-development

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

It's a meta tag, and its description even reads that it shouldn't be used anymore:

> Career development questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. DO NOT USE - Removed as part of "The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012" - See link in Tag Wiki for more information. (to be reviewed for closure only)

Since that event has long since passed, can we circle back and remove/clean up/burninate this particular tag?

EDIT:  Look at the tag synonyms, too:  [career](/questions/tagged/career), [career-advice](/questions/tagged/career-advice), [employment](/questions/tagged/employment), and [job-hunting](/questions/tagged/job-hunting).  Can we put some fire to these, too?

Comment: Yeah, this came up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266417/cs-graduate-admission - AFAICT, **every single question with that tag is closed**.

Comment: Yeah, was looking at that question too.  Was a fair bit shocked to see that there were so many questions still...floating around with that tag.

Comment: @Mysticial: There [aren't any that are still open](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcareer-development%5D+closed%3A0), actually. :) So it's more should all these questions be deleted along with the tag?

Comment: The _only_ way to burninate that tag is to _delete_ every question tagged with it. There's no point otherwise... I would normally be strongly against it but there's nothing in particular that stands out as worth saving.

Comment: @animuson:  If there aren't any that are relatively fresh that could find a suitable home on Programmers, then may they rest in /dev/null.

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEE... Oh, wait. You're talking about the SO tag, not the Programmers one. :(

Comment: @Yannis:  They're not nearly as bad as SO, and [they allow them to an extent](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/590/54997).  Although I don't see a reason why it couldn't get cleaned up, too.

Comment: @Makoto Just noticed your comment about some of the questions potentially finding a home on Programmers. I see only one question that's younger than 60 days (and it sucks), so migrating them it's not an option (even for the good ones).

Comment: If it sucks, then no reason to bother.  Now to pray for burnination.

Comment: It seems more like a Programmers tag, not a Stack Overflow tag.

Comment: *Related*: [Mass clean-up of career-development questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119713), [The great Stack Overflow tag question cleanup of 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012)

Comment: This needs mod power, or quite a large number of high rep user to delete all of them.

Comment: I've burned through five of my delete votes, so at least there's five less of these posts.

Comment: I've been hacking away at this tag slowly but surely, and now it's under 50 questions.  Hopefully it'll get burninated a little faster now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I absolutely agree this tag needs to go from SO; every single question is closed as not constructive or off-topic, and are no longer a good fit for the site.

Having the tag hang around just encourages its use, and unlike the [books](/questions/tagged/books) tag, I don't think there are any questions that are currently maintained or will be furiously protested if removed.