# Will a good [job-interview] where I pass all the [interview-questions] help my [career-development]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

We have the following tags here on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development) (<del>13</del> <del>6</del> <del>4 questions</del>) *all gone*
- [job-interview](/questions/tagged/job-interview) (<del>3</del> <del>1 questions</del>) *all gone*
- <s>[interview-questions](/questions/tagged/interview-questions) (0 questions)</s>  *all gone*

The questions that are tagged with it are either from a distant past where these kind of question lived on Stack Overflow or they tend to be personal advice, hardly useful for future visitors. It also attract [new questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSyI9.png) where it isn't instantly clear MSE isn't the right place for these kind of questions.

[Burnination Criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/158100):

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
  It describes the content, but it is not always unambiguous, also due to lacking tag guidance.
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
  **NO**
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
  If the tag is needed to clarify a question is about career development the question is missing details. So I hardly believe any of those tags will add meaningful information.
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
  Yes, I don't think there will be confusion what a job interview is or if there are any other uses of job interview (or any other tags for that matter)

Do note there are possible duplicates like [Burninate: career-development](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178253/burninate-career-development?rq=1) but those questions ask about burninating the tag from Stack Overflow. And that burnination is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)...

Can we burninate those tags?
If not, what would be suitable tag-wiki's so we have clear advice when and how to use these tags?

Comment: I don't know whether that's going to help you with your career development. but I agree that the tags should be burinated

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that's an angry flower. not a small & cute flower

Comment: Can some of these questions are eligible to be moved to ´the workplace' ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 are you a mod there or familiar what is on-topic there? Maybe ask in their chat if they can chime in first before we take such action.

Comment: It might be worth simply closing anything explicitly off topic, and removing the tags

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that sounds as a plan and will work.

Comment: My idea was not good, just seen the age of those questions (too old to migrate). Iam not a mod there, but some question seemed related, like https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30836/337838 and https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/88682/putting-stackoverflow-or-linkedin-urls-in-resume-cv

Comment: The remaining questions are locked rejected-migrations. If things are working as they should, those should be gone in 30 days or less.

Comment: @ale awesome, thanks for handling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considering the post that triggered this off is clearly off topic - we could probably close anything off topic and removing the tags. If no one's using the tags, they should age away, in 6-8 weeks?

The tags don't even have tag wiki entries, so I suppose folks don't care about it that much.

There's few enough of these that doing so should be relatively non disruptive.

Comment: Agree. Just nuke the questions and the tags will be nuked altogether.